# How does git know who I am when I use ssh to log in?

Tags: github, ssh

I set up SSH login for github using the following instructions, and although it works, I can't figure out why it works: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/

My understanding of SSH is as follows: client creates a key pair, client gives public key to server, and when client wants to log in, he encrypts a message of server's choice using his private key to prove that he is really the client.

Now: I upload my public key XXX to Github. When I do "ssh -T git@github.com", Github has to know I am trying to log in as me, so that he can decrypt my message using XXX, right? So ssh has to send that information...but how does ssh know anything about Github, or what my username is? And what if I have multiple key pairs - which key would ssh use?

Answer (score 4):

In short:

1. SSH client send public key to server
2. Server finds your name according to public key (unique), but needs to verify that you  have also the private key, therefore he sends you a some message
3. Your client signs that message using your private key
4. Server verifies the signature and if it is valid, you are allowed access

This is based on public key cryptography, specially digital signature technique (google for more details).

Comment: Thanks, but  I still have a few queries. (1) Two people can have the same public key, no? Would github ask you to create a new key pair during upload time if it was duplicate? (2) How does ssh know which key to send?

Comment: (1) No. They would have the same private and it is not acceptable. (2) It sends the keys you configure it to send by the `-i` switch or `IdentityFile` option. Or from `ssh-agent`. It tries in sequence and if one fails in point [2], it skips to another.

Comment: @user1299784: Yes, two people *could* have the same public (and therefore private) key. That would be a violation of good security practices, and github would not be able to tell the two people apart.

Comment: @KeithThompson GitHub does not accept duplicate keys. It simply refuses  the second entry. The odds are insanely low though.

Answer (score 4):

When you add your SSH public key to your GitHub account, you associate that key with your GitHub account.

By default, the command `ssh -T git@github.com` searches for *id_dsa* and *id_rsa* files. To confirm this, try `ssh -T git@github.com -v`.

If you have keys associated to different github accounts, you would have to specify with -i to use different accounts. `ssh -T git@github.com -i /path/to/mykey`

Comment: Is `ssh` sending the public key together with the first request then?

Answer (score 0):

In a shared-account scenario, authentication/authorization is handled by the application.

I'm not sure Github is using it, but one solution for non-shell account authorization is [Gitosis](https://github.com/res0nat0r/gitosis), and it used for precisely the purpose you describe. There are separate key pairs for each user. This much is similar to how Github does things.

The basic notion of how Gitosis works (deferring the authentication and authorization to gitosis) is explained on the app readme page, but the mechanics may require a review of the source code. Based on a cursory examination, it looks like the mechanics of this method are mostly via git hooks on the server.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub can only recognize you by your public key because it provides key uniqueness.

In other words, although there's a tiny chance that two users will accidentally generate the same key pair, GitHub simply won't allow that duplicate public key to be attached to the second account.

Regarding the question of how ssh decides which public key to send if there is more than one. By default, ssh takes the key, ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub, unless specified otherwise in the configuration file or passed via the -i parameter